# IntelliJ IDEA Multiple Instance

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA by default has the functionality to debug/run more than one instance of the same program.

For example; if I run debug on Project X and it's main threads is in waiting, sometimes I come back and run it again as the DEBUG button is not indicating a currently executing session. Nor does IntelliJ stop you from running another session of the same program (Project X)

Why is this functionality necessary, and how can I turn it off?

Comment: a) You may want to run the program more than once. b) use the debug button from the debug window only, this will never create additional instances.

Comment: Thanks - guess it's a habit I am going to need to build in. Seems silly though to have this as default. It should be a configuration setting, as most only require one, and then a de-pressed button to indicate a session is running. Interesting & Silly

Comment: It's possible if using before launch interceptors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) The functionality is very good when you want to rerun a configuration in a new instance.
For example a simple client that you want to start in several instances without any other effort.

b) You cannot really turn it off.

This will start a new Run or Debug session:

[image: Start new Run/Debug Session]

This will rerun the current Debug session:

[image: Rerun current Debug Session]

This will show you your current Debug sessions:

[image: Current running sessions]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the `Single instance only` option. To do this,

1. Go to `Edit Configurations...` in the dropdown to the left of the `Run` button.
2. Select the appropriate configuration.
3. Click the `Single instance only` checkbox.